# Does "leaving school at young" imply "uneducated"?

Tags: word-usage

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even?q=even%20though)

> Even though he **left school at 16**, he still managed to become prime minister.

Usually, "even though" indicates two opposite parts in meaning, "left school at 16" and "become prime minister" in this case. Therefore, the first part should be some kind of the opposite of well-educated.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/uneducated), "uneducated" means "having received little or no education".

Is it appropriate to say "leaving school at young implies uneducated"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Young* and *uneducated* are adjectives, but you need nouns or noun phrases in both those locations.

You can say

> Leaving school at a young age implies an incomplete education.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, secondary education ends at the age of eighteen, when the twelfth grade is completed.  Sometimes gifted students can graduate early, but the idiom "left school" generally means "without completing the course of studies."  (And no college.)

Now, sixteen is tenth grade, so he did receive a far amount of education.  It implies a limited education.

Comment: _Prime Minister_ suggests a British context, and we don't have school grades, but the principle is the same. He would have left school without entering the [sixth form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_form) , in which pupils study for the examinations which lead to university admission.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK context, the law requires you to go to school until you are 16. Moreover the government will pay your education until you are 19.  Typically less academic students leave school at 16 (and enter into various forms of training)  More academic students continue school until they are 18. The extra year to age 19 is only if you need to retake a year for various reasons.

So "He left school at 16" implies that he completed only his compulsory education as a boy, and was not "academic".  In the past, this was very common in the UK, and only a minority of people would continue school until 18. So it doesn't imply an "incomplete" education.

It doesn't mean that the person had no further education as an adult.  This sentence particular applies to John Major, who left school at 16 with 3 O-levels, and didn't attend university (but did train as a professional banker) Most Prime Minsters before and all Prime Ministers since John Major left school at 18 and went to university.